# how to include a void method in override ToString method in C#

Tags: c#

Okay, so Im trying to write out a List in an override ToString method. Ive thought about maybe doing it with delegates but delegates require the methods to be static and I don't want to make it static.

Please take a look at my code below and help me to any other way that there might be:

```
private void Print()
    {
        foreach(var i in Lista)
        {
            Console.Write(i);
        }
    }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() + Print();
    }
```

it gives me an error 'Operator + cannot be applied to operands of type string and void'

Thank you for any of your help!

Comment: show us some input and output that you expect... otherwise this question won't do well here.

Comment: Print is void, you cannot add its nonexistant return value to _base,ToString()_ and return whatever the ToString returns

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Do you want to just call `Print` or you need something else?

Answer (score 2):

In your code the method Print is declared to be void. So it cannot be used in a concatenation with the return value from *base.ToString()*. Instead you can change Print to return a string and then you can call it from your override

So for example:

```
private string Print()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(var i in Lista)
    {
        sb.Append(i);
        // or sb.AppendLine(i) if you want a newline added
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}


public override string ToString()
{
    return base.ToString() + Print();
}
```

This solution, of course, doesn't print anything to the console. Instead it returns a string that the caller could decide to output to the console or write to a file. Don't tie a generic class to its output medium. (Unless the scope of the class itself is to output its content to a console/file/printer/etc...).

Answer (score 0):

You can just nix the method and return to the caller:

```
private List<string> Lista = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };

public override string ToString()
{
   return $"{base.ToString()} {String.Join(',', Lista)}";
}
```

If you really want to print to the console:

```
private void Print()
{
    Lista?.ForEach(x => { Console.Write($"{x} "); });
}

public override string ToString()
{
    Print();
    return base.ToString();
}
```